# Massive data file conversion

Tags: json, database

I have a .data file that is +19MB in size.  If I open it in texteditor on my Mac I get the circle of death.  I've tried moving into a json file in Atom, but that too breaks.  It's all on 1 line, so trying to beautify to break down file into manageable chunks is breaking my things too.  I have cut about 150 lines worth, beautified it, and it came out great, but that's kb of data.  I've got a +19MB file.

I've tried multiple ways of cutting and pasting to see if I can make smaller files, but that too breaks everything. Can I get this into sql?

I'm working on my personal project and this data file is critical to my project.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but 19MB does not qualify as "large", let alone "massive". Any decent text editor should have no problem with it. Now, if you mean 19GB...  What type of data is it? JSON? XML?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to coding so I don't know what is big and what isn't.  Sorry!